# How to search MSE for a formula?

Tags: support, search

I don't know how to search a formula in Math.SE. For example last time I asked a question about  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(n \ln \frac{2 n+1}{2 n-1}-1\right)$; but this question has been closed since it's duplicated. But since I don't know how to search a formula, I can't find it myself but can only go through it by links provided by others.
So how can I search for a formula?

Comment: Use [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/) for searching math formulas typeset via mathjax.

Comment: so there isn't a way to directly search in MSE?(though your solving plan is useful, thanks a lot!)

Comment: The title asks about editing but the body seems to be about searching. You should edit the question so that the title and the body match. If it is about searching, you could add the tag ([meta-tag:search]).

Comment: There is a FAQ about searching: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265) You can have a look at [some of the linked questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/29265), too. For example: [How to search for a formula/expression](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10169).

Comment: For future reference: this is a reason why putting formulas in titles is frowned upon.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Is it really? [Asaf's answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30672/42969) to [Under what criteria should we remove questions from the HNQ list?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30671/42969) gives the impression that a title without MathJax is automatically suspicious of being “lazy” or “clickbait” (and I do not agree with that).

Comment: I think this is actually a reason in favor of including the formula in the title (where appropriate).  The FAQ post [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) in the section on titles says: "Use your title to convey as much information about your question as possible." There is also this  post by @GerryMyerson: [More informative titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3785).

Comment: @MartinS, I'll refer you to Steven Stadnicki's comment on that post of mine. It points out that it can be possible, and preferable, to convey the same information with text instead of TeX. And I may not be able to find it, but I'm pretty sure I saw, on this site, a criticism of TeX-heavy titles on main.

Comment: There is some discussion of the perils of TeX-heavy titles at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34508/multiline-mathjax-on-title and the questions listed there under Related.

Comment: It is anticipated that, quite apart from formulas written with $\LaTeX$, previous duplicate Questions can be difficult to locate.  It is actually a part of StackExchange philosophy that we keep a certain number of duplicate Questions on the site (versus deleting them) to make their Answers easier to find through the linked functionality.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, sometimes it is possible to give a good enough description of the question without using any formulas - but sometimes it might be quite difficult. Steven Stadnicki's comment mentions searching - which depends on the tools available for searching. (That comment was before Approach0.) Since we digressed to this topic, I will add this link, too: [Using MathJax/TeX in the titles of questions - yes or no?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10617)